# android apply style based on version

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

In android, I can apply a custom style based on versions:

```
+-res/values-v14/styles.xml
+-res/values/styles.xml
```

but, how can I apply a defined style based on version?

in values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="spinner_textview">
    <item name="style">@android:style/Widget.Spinner></item>
</style>
```

the following line causes error in eclipse

```
<item name="style">@android:style/Widget.Spinner</item>
```

Eclipse says: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 
 'style'.

is there a way that I can apply style based on api version?

**PS: i'm try to apply `@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Spinner` to a `TextView`, but the style is only available in api 14+;**

Comment: If you want to use api level 14+ styles, then you should target your app with targetSdkVersion to that version

Comment: There's a typo in that line, see the > after 'Widget.Spinner'.

Comment: typo fixed, problem persists. @Robert:i have target api 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to specify the style within a style declaration.

Instead, your style should have "@android:style/Widget.Spinner" as it's parent to inherit all it's attributes.

```
<style name="spinner_textview" parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner" >
 ...
</style>
```

This same style should have different parents depending on the version ( by using the values-XX folders )